# Is it possible to encrypt traffic if I have only CA certificate?

Tags: security, openssl, ssl, certificates, mqtt

I have simple secure (I guess) `Mosquitto` server described in my [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/557702/ensure-tls-communication-security-in-mosquitto/557705#557705).

Client machine has no any keys or certificate installed except single ca.crt certificate file generated and taken from `Mosquitto` server.

Is it possible that request performed by simple `MQTT` client below is encrypted and secure?

```
mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.1.8 -t sensor --cafile ca.crt -p 8883 -d
```

This client uses only single certificate file and no keys. Is it somehow possible encrypt traffic by having only certificate and no keys?

Comment: Maybe this question is be better asked on security.stackechange.com?

Comment: When you're browsing to a typical https site (eg https://unix.stackexchange.com/ ), does your browser (firefox, chromium...) require a key, or only CAs to get encrypted traffic?

Comment: If you've correctly configured the mosquitto server with certificates then the connection will be secure.  It's no different to configuring a web-server with certificates and connecting to it with your browser - the connection should be secure.